# Blackberry push sdk error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, blackberry-push

I have installed Blackberry push sdk after referring the BPSS installation guide. All the necessary software has been installed. Now I can access Tomcat home page via the https URL but I cant open any sample URL in push sdk it gives an error saying that

```
HTTP Status 404 - /sample-push-initiator

type Status report

message /sample-push-initiator

description The requested resource (/sample-push-initiator) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

Why is this ?? What I have missed here ??
Please tell me I'm stuck here.
Thanks!

Comment: Solved. Need to use URL like this: https://localhost:8443/high-level-sample/ , then I was able to load the sample push initiator.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer, mark the answer as solved and then you don't need to add the *[Solved]* prefix in question title.

Comment: When send push msg to client app, what is your subscribers name?